# XSLT create a sortable table from DBpedia data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have a XML file from DBPedia which has this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example.xsl"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result2.xsd">
 <head>
  <variable name="manufacturer"/>
  <variable name="name"/>
  <variable name="car"/>
 </head>
 <results distinct="false" ordered="true">
  <result>
   <binding name="manufacturer"><literal xml:lang="en">Ford Motor Company</literal></binding>
   <binding name="name"><literal xml:lang="en">Lincoln Mark VIII</literal></binding>
   <binding name="car"><uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lincoln_Mark_VIII</uri></binding>
  </result>
  <result>
   <binding name="manufacturer"><literal xml:lang="en">Ford Motor Company</literal></binding>
   <binding name="name"><literal xml:lang="en">Lincoln Continental Mark VI</literal></binding>
   <binding name="car"><uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lincoln_Continental_Mark_VI</uri></binding>
  </result>
 </results>
</sparql>
```

And this is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:sp="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:template match="sp:sparql">
    <html>
      <head><title>XSLT demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sp:result">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sp:binding[@name='manufacturer']"/></td>
      <xsl:variable name="NAME"><xsl:value-of select="sp:binding[@name='car']"/></xsl:variable>
      <td><a href="{$NAME}"><xsl:value-of select="sp:binding[@name='name']"/>  </a></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I make this table sortable with Javascript or any other way? I've already tried sorttable.js and TableSorter but they do not seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: table sorting scripts should work fine. post one not working and we can help from there.

Comment: I've followed this example but I can't get it to work .... http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
I've also tried this one but it also doesn't seem to work .... http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: A general rule for XSLT questions is that you need to show your input and your desired output. Your output is HTML plus Javascript. If you don't know what output you want to produce (that is, what HTML+JS will work), then you have an HTML/JS problem, not an XSLT problem. So the tags you have chosen are directing your question to the wrong audience, and make it less likely you will get an answer.

Comment: It is simpe. I give you all the code that I use. The above code produces just a table. I want this table sortable if the user clicks the header of the table. It is so simple. It does not get any simpler. It also is an XSLT problem because the Javascript libraries do not work with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using xslt to sort xml via onclick function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572847/using-xslt-to-sort-xml-via-onclick-function)