# Sorting results from xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sorting

I am currently creating a small application which requires me to read information from an xml file to populate a web page.

I have a JavaScript function which takes 1 parameter (mood = String). The function uses the responseText from a XMLHttpRequest which looks at the xml file and returns all 'programs' which correspond to the mood parameter:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {    // IE 5/6
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET", "programme_catalog.xml", false); 
xhttp.send(); 
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

function getContent(mood) {
    $(xmlDoc).find("program").each(function(){
            if ($(this).find('mood').text() == mood) {
            $("#sky-recommender").append(
                '<div id=\'program-holder\'> <div id=\'program-cover\'><img height="130px" width="188px" src=\"' + $(this).find('image').text() + '\" /> </div> <div id=\'program-title\'><p>' + $(this).find('name').text() + 
                '</p></div></div>'
                );
            }
        });
}
```

An entry in my xml file:

```
<program id="10"> 
        <name>Foo</name>
        <mood>Bar</mood> 
        <image>/program-images/file-name.123</image> 
    </program>
```

The xml file can consist of many entries with the same 'mood' but I want to limit the `getContent` function to only return 5 results sorted by the program id in ascending order.

I'm guessing I could place a for loop around the content of `getContent()` but I am unsure how to sort them correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and feel free to ask if I have forgotten some information.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do  you want to fetch the first five in the document and then sort those?  Or do you want to fetch them all, sort them, and then choose the first five?  In either case, sorting an array is fairly simple: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I'm looking to fetch them all, sort them, and choose 5 starting from the highest id (most recent)

Comment: I was thinking to use an array, but i'm not just obtaining 1 string from each result. I'm getting <name>, <mood>, <image>

Comment: Sorting on one field of an object is not difficult:  `list.sort((o1, o2) => o1.name > o2.name ? -1 : o1.name < o2.name ? 1 : 0)` for descending... reverse `<` / `>` signs for ascending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably leverage an XPath to do this:

```
...
xhttp.open("GET", "programme_catalog.xml", false); 
xhttp.send(); 
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML; 

var nsResolver = xmlDoc.createNSResolver( xmlDoc.ownerDocument == null ? xmlDoc.documentElement : xmlDoc.ownerDocument.documentElement);

var pageStart = 0;
var pageEnd = 5;
var personIterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('//program[./mood[.='Bar'] and position() >= ' + pageStart + ' and position() <= ' + pageEnd, xmlDoc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Note the trickiness to 'page' these results. It might not be the most efficient or fastest solution.

Im not quite sure what you want to do with the sorting? The 5 results you get? Or sort the full document?

You could pull all of the objects out with `'//program[./mood[.='Bar']'` for your XPATH, and then sort the resulting nodes in an array

Upon more thinking, you probably want to sort the entire document, which is doable with XSLT, but that may be out of scope for your project [question / answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12572847/703644). You would want to sort the XML response before running your XPATH(s)

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)